# Pentaho Data Integration: Data Warehouse dimensions: Transformations in one job

Tags: pentaho, data-warehouse, dimensions, pentaho-data-integration, pdi

I'm creating a Data Warehouse and I'm using Pentaho Data Integration for the ETL.
I have 2 options:

- Each dimension ETL in its own transformation (I have to open all the transformation files to run my dimensions), I thought this might be practical if I want to run one dimension only for example.
- Gather all the dimensions in one transformation. (Is this considered like creating a new job in PDI that includes all the transformation? If it is, what is the best way to relate the transformations?)

I'm new to all of this, by the way.

Any suggestions?

Thank you.

Comment: Yes correct, you have to create one job , select transformation steps for all the dimension ktr and run.

Comment: Thank you. That did work. I also made the Job entries run in parallel to load the dimensions in a synchronous way.